Why would you need a second pole on a double-pole relay?
I've watched a tutorial on double-pole relays:
https://youtu.be/n594CkrP6xE?si=RBcEO9Cu-8ZGn_Sj&t=620
And I don't understand: why would you need a second pole on a double-pole relay?
If the two poles are either both open or both closed, why not connect the second device to the first pole?


The example is just showing the concept of a double pole relay, but implements a circuit that could be implemented just as well with a single pole relay.
You can consider to use the two poles of a relay to be used for two completely different purposes, such as one pole switching a mains voltage heater and the other pole drives a 12V lamp to show when heater is on.
Another example could be a muting circuit that disconnects your speakers from the amplifier when you plug in a headset. One pole would disconnect left speaker, the other pole would disconnect right speaker.

Got it, thanks! So we could use two different devices with two different power sources and two different voltages, right?

The second pole does not carry the same signal as the first pole. In fact, paralleling poles on a relay is almost always forbidden from a current-carrying perspective.

Sorry, maybe I've used the wrong term. The two poles are either both open or both closed, right? Why not connect two devices to one pole? P.S. Added a link to the tutorial and a picture.

@Kolyunya There are all manner of combinations, they'll be called something like "2 NO" in which case it is 2 poles normally open, or "1 NO 1 NC" in which case one pole is normally open and one normally closed. There are latching relays, there are relays with multiple coils etc etc.
